# Matching all the word permutations of a string with Ruby Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I've a string of words :

```
string = "Ruby web framework"
```

How can I write a regex matching all the possible word permutation ?

All the following strings have to match :

```
ruby web framework
web framework ruby
framework ruby web

ruby framework web
framework web ruby
web ruby framework
```

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced your ultimate problem statement is best solved with a regex. You also don't state if a permutation must contain *all* words; if so, three `[foo|bar|baz]+` clauses is likely enough. But is this really the end goal? Or are you trying to do fuzzy text searching/matching?

Comment: should this regex match `ruby ruby ruby` and other permutations like this?

Comment: @Dave Newton: the permutation must be ordered starting from those containing all words ..., and degrading eventually with less matches. Last resoult could match just one word

Comment: @Alex Kliuchnikau:  "ruby ruby ruby" should not match ( or better, they have to match as they were just a word: "ruby".

Comment: So we also need regexes for 'ruby web' and 'web ruby', and 'ruby' etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to point out that using a regex isn't the fastest path to this goal:

```
pp string.split.permutation.to_a

[["Ruby", "web", "framework"],
 ["Ruby", "framework", "web"],
 ["web", "Ruby", "framework"],
 ["web", "framework", "Ruby"],
 ["framework", "Ruby", "web"],
 ["framework", "web", "Ruby"]]
```

---

Sigh... OK... here is how I'd do it:

```
require 'pp'

string = "Ruby web framework"
strings_to_search = string.split.permutation.map{ |p| 'Lorem, ' + p.join(' ') + ' consectetur'}

strings_to_search << 'Lorem, Ruby consectetur' 
strings_to_search << 'Lorem, Ruby web consectetur' 
strings_to_search << 'Lorem, Ruby Ruby Ruby' 

pp strings_to_search.map{ |p| p.scan(Regexp.union(string.split)) }
```

And what's happening:

```
1.9.2-p290 :001 >     require 'pp'
true
1.9.2-p290 :002 > 
1.9.2-p290 :003 >       string = "Ruby web framework"
"Ruby web framework"
1.9.2-p290 :004 >     strings_to_search = string.split.permutation.map{ |p| 'Lorem, ' + p.join(' ') + ' consectetur'}
[
    [0] "Lorem, Ruby web framework consectetur",
    [1] "Lorem, Ruby framework web consectetur",
    [2] "Lorem, web Ruby framework consectetur",
    [3] "Lorem, web framework Ruby consectetur",
    [4] "Lorem, framework Ruby web consectetur",
    [5] "Lorem, framework web Ruby consectetur"
]
1.9.2-p290 :005 > 
1.9.2-p290 :006 >       strings_to_search << 'Lorem, Ruby consectetur' 
[
    [0] "Lorem, Ruby web framework consectetur",
    [1] "Lorem, Ruby framework web consectetur",
    [2] "Lorem, web Ruby framework consectetur",
    [3] "Lorem, web framework Ruby consectetur",
    [4] "Lorem, framework Ruby web consectetur",
    [5] "Lorem, framework web Ruby consectetur",
    [6] "Lorem, Ruby consectetur"
]
1.9.2-p290 :007 >     strings_to_search << 'Lorem, Ruby web consectetur' 
[
    [0] "Lorem, Ruby web framework consectetur",
    [1] "Lorem, Ruby framework web consectetur",
    [2] "Lorem, web Ruby framework consectetur",
    [3] "Lorem, web framework Ruby consectetur",
    [4] "Lorem, framework Ruby web consectetur",
    [5] "Lorem, framework web Ruby consectetur",
    [6] "Lorem, Ruby consectetur",
    [7] "Lorem, Ruby web consectetur"
]
1.9.2-p290 :008 >     strings_to_search << 'Lorem, Ruby Ruby Ruby' 
[
    [0] "Lorem, Ruby web framework consectetur",
    [1] "Lorem, Ruby framework web consectetur",
    [2] "Lorem, web Ruby framework consectetur",
    [3] "Lorem, web framework Ruby consectetur",
    [4] "Lorem, framework Ruby web consectetur",
    [5] "Lorem, framework web Ruby consectetur",
    [6] "Lorem, Ruby consectetur",
    [7] "Lorem, Ruby web consectetur",
    [8] "Lorem, Ruby Ruby Ruby"
]
1.9.2-p290 :009 > 
1.9.2-p290 :010 >       pp strings_to_search.map{ |p| p.scan(Regexp.union(string.split)) }
[["Ruby", "web", "framework"],
 ["Ruby", "framework", "web"],
 ["web", "Ruby", "framework"],
 ["web", "framework", "Ruby"],
 ["framework", "Ruby", "web"],
 ["framework", "web", "Ruby"],
 ["Ruby"],
 ["Ruby", "web"],
 ["Ruby", "Ruby", "Ruby"]]
[
    [0] [
        [0] "Ruby",
        [1] "web",
        [2] "framework"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "Ruby",
        [1] "framework",
        [2] "web"
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] "web",
        [1] "Ruby",
        [2] "framework"
    ],
    [3] [
        [0] "web",
        [1] "framework",
        [2] "Ruby"
    ],
    [4] [
        [0] "framework",
        [1] "Ruby",
        [2] "web"
    ],
    [5] [
        [0] "framework",
        [1] "web",
        [2] "Ruby"
    ],
    [6] [
        [0] "Ruby"
    ],
    [7] [
        [0] "Ruby",
        [1] "web"
    ],
    [8] [
        [0] "Ruby",
        [1] "Ruby",
        [2] "Ruby"
    ]
]
```

Once you have the hits, *THEN* you filter out the ones that shouldn't be accepted. Don't try to do it all in regex, because you will make a pattern that becomes too unwieldy and is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: great, but then I need something to match any array (or a part of it) with a given text. I asked for regex, to check if a combination of words exist in a given phrase or not ...

Comment: @LucaG.Soave, I broke it down for you.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
   theRegex=Regexp.new("("+(Regexp.union(str.split(' ')).inspect.chop[1..-1])+"){#{str.split(' ').length}}")
```

The generated regex is `/(ruby|web|development){3}/`. Is this what you want?

Comment: "This (may) work"? DId you try it? Can you show results to the OP?

Comment: Won't this match `ruby ruby ruby` also?